# Poisson and exponential distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

If number of occurrences per time unit of some event is a random variable $X\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, then the time between occurrences is a random variable $Y$ which has exponential distribution.

What isn't stated clearly anywhere is that is the parameter of the exponential distribution the same $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, more precisely, if the number of arrivals in  an interval $t$ is Poisson $Po(\lambda)$, then the time between two consecutive arrivals is Exponential with mean $1/\lambda$.

Proof:

$$F_T(t)=P(T\leq t)=1-P(T>t)$$

Where $P(T>t)$ means: "calculate the probability that, in a size $t$ interval there are no arrivals".

In other words

$$P(T>t)=e^{-\lambda t}$$

that is

$$1-P(T>t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$$

which is exactly the CDF of an exponential $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$